# SFML moving two players with different buttons at the same time

Tags: sfml

I've created simple game using SFML(player can run, jump etc pressing arrows), how can i make the same for two players(second player will use WASD to move) at the same time on one computer?

Comment: Hi Papi4, welcome to StackOverflow. Can show us what you've tried? Please take the time to read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: A quick warning about 2 players 1 kbd, cheap keyboards can ghost and block. I'd recommend having controller support as well. but the user could use 2 keyboards I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the keys pressed with the `sf::Keyboard` class. `sf::Keyboard` is a static class so you don't need to create a unique instance, here is a quick example:

```
if(sf::Keyboard::isKeypressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::W))
{
    Player1.Move(1, 1);
}

if(sf::Keyboard::isKeypressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::Left))
{
    Player2.Move(1, 1);
}
```

I'm assuming you currently are using `window.PollEvent(event)`, the problem with that approach is that you only poll one event per loop cycle since events are added into a queue. With the above code you should be able to press multiple keys at the same time and have two actions processed.

Comment: Not quite true RE events - you can (and should) process the entire event queue every loop, and can easily handly multiple button presses